# Jelly-Bean updated Galaxy Tab 2 7" can't connect to Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, usb, adb, android-4.2-jelly-bean, galaxy-tab

I've just updated my Galaxy Tab 2 7" to OS v4.1.1 (Jelly Bean). Since that I can't connect to my device (from my Windows 8 PC, via USB) anymore.
Most relevant to me is the fact that I can't even debug my Android apps using the tablet (which is actually the reason why I bought it). **Eclipse** does show it among the adb devices, but in an *offline* status.

The Android SDK is updated. I've tried to force the install of the drivers via the **android_winusb.inf** located in the
*\android-sdk-windows\extras\google\usb_driver*
 folder, but it doesn't seem to carry the right pieces of information. Tampering the file by manually adding 'em seems to conflict with the along-coming *.cat* files.
I've also tried by installing **Kies**, but even that piece of software can't connect to the device.

What do you suggest? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magically, a new OTA update has come "from above" right to my device just a couple of minutes ago. That fixed the whole thing (no action made on the PC side).

Looking at the "about device" data sheet, Android version is still 4.1.1.
I haven't tracked the previous kernel version nor build number, so I can't see if and how they've changed; but I can write 'em down now, just in the case it may matter for someone else to check against:

```
Kernel version
3.0.31 - 523998

Build number
JRO03C.P3110XXCLK7
```